# Slick carousel moving nav dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I am using http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick carousel and I need to limit dots number to 8 even if there more than 8 slides.

Nav dots should have arrows to the left and to the right that suggest user that there are more dots to show.

Can anybody suggest a solution / had similar experience in customizing nav dots with slick?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can also do this with [bootstrap](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/p0etnd71/)

Comment: My current project doesn't use bootsrap...

Comment: you can go for **Slider Syncing** example of slick-slider, and use dots as `slider-nav` for `slider-for`, it will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a [solution](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1799) to limit the number of dots to three using CSS

```
/* hiding all bullets by default */
.slick-dots li {
    display: none
}
/* only displaying the active bullets and the 2 bullets next to it */
.slick-dots li.slick-active,
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li,
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li + li {
    display: block;
}
/* displaying the last three bullets when slick-active class isn't applied to any li before them  */
.slick-dots li:nth-last-child(1),
.slick-dots li:nth-last-child(2),
.slick-dots li:nth-last-child(3) {
    display: block;
}
/* hiding the last three bullets if slick-active exist before them */
.slick-dots li.slick-active ~ li:nth-last-child(1),
.slick-dots li.slick-active ~ li:nth-last-child(2),
.slick-dots li.slick-active ~ li:nth-last-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
/* specific conditions to always display the last three bullets */
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li + li:nth-last-child(3),
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li + li:nth-last-child(2),
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li + li:nth-last-child(1),
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li:nth-last-child(3),
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li:nth-last-child(2),
.slick-dots li.slick-active + li:nth-last-child(1){
    display: block;
}
```

Of course this can be made pretty with preprocessors but it is working.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1gLn1cbg/

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed something like this, you can restrict this to as many dots as you like. I have done it for 5 dots, after that additional dots are not shown, but scroll when your main slides scroll.

You can use the init and change events to accomplish this.

`slickSlider.on('init', function (event, slick) {`

`slickSlider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick) {`

Working example: https://codepen.io/swarad07/pen/xmzQKm

This is very similar to how Instagram does it, with edge dots smaller in size.

Comment: Do you use slick.js to make this work? https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js

Comment: ? I can see that you use some classes from slick but i am not sure because of no documentations. @Swarad Mokal

Comment: So yes I do make use of slick classes to make it work. If you check the code it uses the events and methods provided by slick to make the logic work.

Comment: Hi, your approach is great. I just wonder what should be updated to keep the blue active dot in the middle (third position) instead of forth.