# Show instagram style dots in slick slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm using the slick slider to show a lot of slider items.
I also need to use dots to show the position of the items.
At the moment, there are a lot of dots and I want do show the dots like instagram does.

Here is what i mean:

[image]

There should always be max 6 dots visible. Starting with the first one on the left side.

Is there any way to adress the 4 dots in the middle? At the moment I could only adress the active dot with it's class `slick-active`. But I need the dots before and after the active dot.

Here is my actual slider code: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/ZrKpWY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function to access the prevoius and next element.

I've updated your codepen example here: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQvpjo?editors=1010#0)

```
$('li.slick-active').prev().css('background-color', 'red');
$('li.slick-active').next().css('background-color', 'orange');
```

Comment: looks good, thanks! is there a way to add a class (`active-prev` and `active-next`) to the links instead of only the background-styles?

Comment: sure, you can use addClass: `$('li.slick-active').prev().addClass('active-prev');`

Comment: great, thanks a lot!

Comment: have you managed to implement the instagram style dot navigation? If so could you update the codepen? cheers jan

Comment: have you solved to style it like Instagram? need the same style... can you update your Codepen?

Answer (score 3):

I have developed Instagram Stick slider with jQuery.
you can use in this link.
https://github.com/SolvingMan/Instagram-Stick-Slider-jQuery

live Demo:

- https://140.82.58.117/tingshop/
- http://bullsrvr.com/slider/demo/

[image]

Comment: even thought this may solve the issue, it would be nice to add some more explanation.

Comment: The answer seems incorrect,

I recently developed something like this, you can restrict this to as many dots as you like. I have done it for 5 dots, after that additional dots are not shown, but scroll when your main slides scroll.

You can use the init and change events to accomplish this.

```slickSlider.on('init', function (event, slick) {

slickSlider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick) {```

Working example: https://codepen.io/swarad07/pen/xmzQKm

This is very similar to how Instagram does it, with edge dots smaller in size.

Check this question for more details

Comment: Check this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122912/slick-carousel-moving-nav-dots/54093399#54093399

Comment: How to do with react-slick in reactjs?